# How to algebraically prove the following inequation?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, functional-equations

Following is the inequation I have been trying to prove for a while.

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}(1-q)}{\frac{1}{2}(1-q) + pq}\neq \frac{\frac{1}{4}(1-q)}{\frac{1}{4}(1-q) + p^2q} + \frac{\frac{1}{4}(1-q)}{\frac{1}{4}(1-q) + qp(1-p)} $$

Of course, I tried the basic cancellation out but the expressions only got bigger. It also occurred to me that I didn't how prove that their NOT equal. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: write both sides as a single fraction with the same denominator. (This may have to be huge but maybe you can factor it cleverly so it doesn't have to be that huge). Then expand both numerators so that they're sums of products of $q$ and $p$ (i.e. something like $a + b + cq + dp + eqp + fq^2 + gp^2 + \cdots$). If these expressions disagree, the polynomials aren't equal. Of course they may be equal *sometimes* - i.e. if $q$ and $p$ have specific values.

Comment: They are definitely different when $p=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the two expressions are equal when $q=1$ and $0<p<1$, so assume that $q\ne 1$; the inequality can then be simplified to

$$\frac1{1-q+2pq}\ne\frac1{1-q+4p^2q}+\frac1{1-q+4qp(1-p)}$$

and then, putting the righthand side over a common denominator, to

$$\frac1{1-q+2pq}\ne\frac{2-2q+4pq}{(1-q)^2+4pq(1-q)+16p^3q^2(1-p)}\;.$$

Assuming that the denominators are not zero, this holds if and only if

$$\begin{align*}
(1-q)^2+4pq(1-q)+16p^3q^2(1-p)&\ne 2(1-q+2pq)^2\\
&=4(1-q)^2+16pq(1-q)+16p^2q^2\;,
\end{align*}$$

or

$$3(1-q)^2+12pq(1-q)+16p^2q^2\big(1-p(1-p)\big)\ne 0\;.$$

This is clearly the case when $0\le p\le 1$ and $0<q<1$.